# show that $λ=0$ is an eigenvalue of the regular Sturm- Liouville system

Tags: sturm-liouville

show that $λ=0$ is an eigenvalue of the regular Sturm- Liouville system

$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}[p(x){y}']+\lambda r(x)y=0$

${y}'(0)=0$

${y}'(1)=0$

What I have done is this:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}[p(x){y}']+\lambda r(x)y=0$

$p(x){y}''+{p}'(x){y}'+\lambda r(x)y=0$

$\lambda =0$

$p(x){y}''+{p}'(x){y}'=0$

I've to confess that I'm a bit lost, can anyone give me a hint ?

Comment: Hint: try $y \equiv 1$.

Comment: It is clear that for $\lambda=0$, there are non-trivial solutions, say $y(x)=c$ for any $c\in\Bbb R$.